# How to securely pass sensitive text to a file in a Docker image for use in AWS ECS Fargate?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I've got a Dockerfile for building a Docker image used in AWS ECS Fargate.

My question is, can I pass a text string file to the Docker image? Creating the file is easy with "RUN touch example.txt" in the Dockerfile, but how can I securely pass sensitive text to that file without showing it in plain text?

Thanks

Comment: You can't really.  Docker doesn't have any native encryption capabilities, so either you need to include the file in plain text or include the decryption key in the image.  Usually you pass credentials and other secret values via some other path, rather than building them into the image.

Comment: I can pass the credentials from secrets manager using valueFrom from ECS Fargate. But how can i pass that credential to a specific file from the image?

Answer (score -1):

You can use docker build secrets to expose secrets during build time. You can use API tokens and sensitive info during your build, and it won't be shown in plain text in the build logs.

Hope this helps, more info here: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/secrets/